# problem with jquery code

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to fill a div on my page with some html elements using jquery

below is my code:

```
$(this).find('div').html('<table><tr><td class=td colspan=2><p class=hilightedtext>Please enter email and password form which you want to import contacts.</p></td></tr><tr><td align=right class=td ><label>Email :</label></td><td><input  type=text name=email_box  size=35></td></tr><tr><td align=right class=td><label>Password :</label></td><td><input type=password name=password_box size=35></td></tr><tr class=thTableImportantRow><td colspan=2 align=center valign=bottom><input class=register_now  type=submit name=import value=Import&nbsp;Contacts></tr></table>');
```

Problem here is elements are comming properly in div but I can't perform any action on these elements like I can't type anything in text boxes and click on button is also not working.

Please check and help me where is problem ?

Comment: It works for me! (Firefox/Linux) : http://jsfiddle.net/dR3dm/

Comment: First of all enclose attributes in double quotes.

Comment: paste your complete code in jsfiddle

Comment: @SalmanPK :already tried with it but no change. Actyully my whole JS and html is enclosed in php double quotes

Comment: what is $(this) referring to?

Comment: @SalmanPK : It does't matter code is enclosed in php double quotes

Comment: @Alfred At least you will start to realize why it is not a good practice :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa :Actually its a open source plugin by openInviter am doing some js changes. So I have to follow his coding style

Comment: Could you insert then the whole code you use? Including the PHP mess? I don't think a plugin would force you to use terrible coding style, but if yes, maybe you should not use it.